# Linux Bash Scripting Proxy Variable

Tags: linux, bash, proxy

In linux we can change the variable of http_proxy in terminal by `export http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:x`. But I want to do it with script. So I have following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="_reliable_list.txt"

for line in $(cat $FILE)
do
    proxy="http://$line"
    export http_proxy=$proxy
done
```

At the end on the same terminal when I check the value of variable http_proxy, it is null.
I want to read from file proxy addresses and export them to http_proxy variable, and after use it with wget. Simply I want to automate this code:

```
export http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:x
wget mysite.com
```

If any other ideas I will be very glad.

Comment: Why do you set the proxy in a loop? what is the last line in input file?

Comment: Because I need every request with new proxy address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the script to embed wget call, assuming a new file containing urls:

```
#!/bin/bash

URLS="_url_list.txt"
FILE="_reliable_list.txt"

i=1
for line in $(cat $FILE)
do
    export http_proxy="http://$line"
    wget $(head $i $URLS | tail -1 | tr -d '\n')
    let i++
done
```

Comment: @user873286, it works here, does "URL" show up in your error message? Can you try to run this: "export http_proxy=217.196.113.81:8080; wget google.com"

Comment: yes for single variable it works, but when I read from file, it says bad port, I think it is because of last character carriage or newline character, do you know how to strip them?

Comment: added `tr -d '\n'` to the answer

Comment: wget $(head $i $URLS | tail -1 | tr -d '\n') this line I do not need at all, so I call it like wget http://www.example.com | tr -d '\n' will this be correct

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you want to `source` that file instead of running it. When you use `export`, it does not propagate to the calling shell.

Second, your code isn't very good. You should use `bash`'s file reading capabilities instead of `cat`. Also, your code just picks the last line in that file and uses that as the proxy, are you sure that's what you wanted to do? If so, you can just use `tail`.

Comment: No what I want to do, to get every line and use it as proxy address then call wget, then continue this process until the end of file

Comment: @user873286: Then you can't do it like that, you have to put the call to `wget -c` inside the loop.

Comment: yes I know, but before I wanted to chechk whether it works or not, is wget -c is enough?

Comment: @user873286: The only problem with `wget -c` is that if you have a file with the same name on the first call to `wget`, then it will try to "continue" it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of cat FILE I always use "while read".

I don't know if it makes a difference here or if there is a reason to use one over the other.

Example:

```
while read LINE
do

  export http_proxy="http://${LINE}"

done < $INPUT_FILE
```

Comment: Kind of tangential to the question, but +1 for good advice. It makes a difference if there is whitespace (other than newlines) in the input file: for-loops are subject to word-splitting; `read` is not.

Comment: when write like these (even in for case): export http_proxy:"http://$LINE"; wget $URL. I get error:: Bad port number.y URL http://217.196.113.81:8080

Comment: Oops.Sorry.  You might need to wrap the variable in quotes.  I've modified the example above.  Actually, perreal did that in the previous example

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this on command line:

```
export http_proxy="$(tail -1 _reliable_list.txt)"
```

OR else if you have above line in a script say script.sh then run in like this:

```
. ./script.sh
```

to get exported variables in current shell.